# Js array: If first element exists then perform .foo otherwise null

Tags: javascript

In JS, for simple variables we can do like `x?.foo`

Can I do this for array too?

```
a[0]?.foo
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Wouldn't simply trying it in your devtools console or node repl have been a lot faster than posting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use the optional chaining operator with an array, you just need to add a dot before calling the index

```
a?.[0]?.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, altough your array may not be null, you don't know if an item with the index `0` exists. However, the `?` operator only accesses the property `foo` if the expression before evaluates something that is not `null` or `undefined`.

#### Example

```js
var x = [];

console.log(x[0]?.foo); // undefined
console.log(x[0].foo); // error

x = [{foo: 1}];

console.log(x[0]?.foo); // 1
console.log(x[0].foo); // 1
```

Keep in mind that accessing an array at an index without knowing if that index exists is risky and should not be done unless really needed.

Also, try testing before asking simple questions like these.

Comment: To protect from the array not existing, they could use another optional chaining operator: `a?.[0]?.foo`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use this.

I feel you should at the very least try and do this in an online js-sandbox tool before asking these simple questions.

```js
// objects
const items0 = {foo: 'bar'};
console.log(items0?.foo)

// arrays
const items1 = [{foo: 'bar'}];
console.log(items1[0]?.foo)

// functions
const items2 = () => ({ foo: 'bar' });
console.log(items2()?.foo)
```